# the use of fflush(FILE* stream)

Tags: c, io, fflush

I Really can't understand the use of the : `fflush()` function , could I find a good implementation of this function ?  I read some resources about it but I still can't grasp it well , actually I want to know what this function really do ?

Comment: http://git.musl-libc.org/cgit/musl/tree/src/stdio/fflush.c

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The best way to know what it does is the standard

> **7.21.5.2 The fflush function**
>
> **Synopsis**
>
> 1. ```
>    #include <stdio.h>
>    int fflush(FILE *stream);
>    ```
>
> **Description**
>
> 2. If `stream` points to an output stream or an update stream in which the most recent operation was not input, the `fflush` function causes any unwritten data for that stream to be delivered to the host environment to be written to the file; otherwise, the behavior is undefined.
> 3. If `stream` is a null pointer, the `fflush` function performs this flushing action on all streams for which the behavior is defined above.
>
> **Returns**
>
> 4. The `fflush` function sets the error indicator for the stream and returns `EOF` if a write error occurs, otherwise it returns zero.

So basically the the library I/O functions use buffers, `fflush()` moves the data from the buffers to the *physical* file, that's why `fflush(stdin)` as you can understand from above is undefined behavior, because `fflush()` is only defined for **output** streams.

The above means, that write operations on output streams are not performed immediately, they are buffered, when you call `fflush()` then they are flushed to the disk, you don't need to `fflush()` explicitly all the time, for example in

```
fpritnf(stdout, "Example text\n");
```

the `"\n"` at the end of the printed text, triggers a flush automatically, also when you call `fclose()` or exit the program the buffers are flushed.

You may also notice, that even for output streams the behavior is not defined unless the most recent operation is **output**, input operations cannot be flushed.

Answer (score 2):

Quoting `C11` standard, chapter 7.21.5.2

> `int fflush(FILE *stream);`
>
> If `stream` points to an output stream or an update stream in which the most recent operation was not input, the `fflush()` function causes any unwritten data for that stream to be delivered to the host environment to be written to the file; otherwise, the behavior is undefined.

So, basically, the `fflush(stream)` call will *forcefully* (even if the buffer is not full) flush out any data that is present in the buffer associated with that particular `stream` to the *output file* (disk).

Also, as a note, from paragraph 3, same document

> If `stream` is a null pointer, the `fflush()` function performs this flushing action on all streams for which the behavior is defined above.

Comment: Disk I/O is expensive and the kernel for your particular OS maintains a buffer for writing to the disk.  When that buffer is "close to full" it will write the contents to disk.  `fflush` is a way for you to tell it to dump the buffer to disk NOW.

Comment: @jnbbender yeah, right. I've added the _forcefully_ part now. :-)

Comment: @jnbbender Kernels don't maintain stdio buffers, the stdio part of the C library does.

Answer (score 1):

`fflush` is needed when you need to control when output written to a stdio `FILE` actually becomes visible, since stdio normally buffers output and writes a large chunk as a unit. For basic C programs not using any interfaces with the operating system outside of the C standard library, the main/only time you need this kind of control is when the output is being shown on an interactive device (screen/terminal) and you want to make sure it's physically visible there. On unix-like/POSIX systems and in other environments with multiprocessing, though, you may also want to ensure that data is written out to files or pipes that other processes might need to read.

Answer (score 1):

When you write to a `FILE*` using e.g. `fprintf` (or even `printf` which is about equal to `fprintf(stdout, ...)`) the data is normally stored in a buffer. When the buffer is full it is *flushed* (written) to the actual output file.

If you want to write the contents of the buffer to the file *before* it is full, you can call `fflush` which does just that.

Answer (score 1):

The streams can be buffered. That mean's that after using a function like `printf` or `fprintf` the characters you send don't go immediately. Instead they wait for proper situation to be sent.

This can creates some problems because It can sometimes take a long time for the stream the finally come through.

For that reason there is a command `fflush(FILE *stream)` which *forces* the stream.

In Unix system a program always has 3 file descriptors open:

1. `stdin` - input to your program, buffered
2. `stdout` - output of your program, buffered
3. `stderr` - output for error messages, unbuffered

So when you are using descriptor `stdout` ( `printf` does that) and you want to be shure that the characters show up right ahead, use `fflush`.